# UISegmented view to change views

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have set up two barbutton items one on the right and one on the left. The right one successfully changes between two views, and the second one ont the right is a segmented control which is supposed to change between two views like wise. Here is my code, i want to know how to implement changing views with the segmented control.

```
- (void)setupNavigationBar {
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];
    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"ContainerView"];
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward target:self action:@selector(switchViewControllers)];
    navBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
    segmented = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"seg1.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"seg1.png"],
                                   nil]];
    segmented.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);

    segmented.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

    UIBarButtonItem * segmentedBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithCustomView:segmented];
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = segmentedBarItem;

    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This is just for the purpose of calling the switch method.
    [self setupNavigationBar];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 436);

    currentViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    currentViewController.view.frame = rect;

    nextViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    nextViewController.view.frame = rect;

    [self addChildViewController:currentViewController];
    [self addChildViewController:nextViewController];

    [self.view addSubview:currentViewController.view];
}

- (void)switchViewControllers {
    [self transitionFromViewController:currentViewController toViewController:nextViewController duration:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        UIViewController *tempViewController = currentViewController;
        currentViewController = nextViewController;
        nextViewController = tempViewController;
        tempViewController = nil;
    }];
}
```

How would I implement the segmented control to change views?

Comment: Why not have use viewController with two sub views. Then use the segment control to toggle which view is visible. You could even animate them when the uses switches. I use the same theory to toggle between a UICollectionView and a UITableView in my app.

Comment: where u wnat to segment controller?

Comment: I thought of that but not clear on how to effectively carry it out

Comment: @iPatel, the segment controller should be on the left hand side of the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For add `UISegmentedControl` on `UINavigationBar`

**EDIT :**

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                      nil];

UISegmentedControl* menuSegmentedButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
menuSegmentedButton.momentary = YES;
menuSegmentedButton.selected = NO;
menuSegmentedButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
   [menuSegmentedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doMenu)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[menuSegmentedButton sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem* barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithCustomView:menuSegmentedButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Add this method for segment button tapped

```
-(void)doMenu
{
    /// code for segment button tapped
}
```

Comment: I wanted images in the segemted control not strings :/

Answer (score 1):

I guess performance issues may require having separate view controllers rather than two subviews but it is much more complex - You would have a very complicated navigation system and would need to set the segment control for each view. I am sure there is another way to subclass a view but I am unfamiliar with this so would suggest having one view controller containing your views.

**Note:** If you were to programmatically create all the objects in each view, you could achieve great performance by removing objects from any hidden views.

So first you have a UISegmentedControl (as created in iPatel's answer). But add in this line `[ctrl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchViewControllers) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Then in `switchViewControllers` put:

```
if (ctrl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    NSLog(@"One");
    self.viewOne.hidden = NO;
    self.viewTwo.hidden = YES;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@"showView" forKey:@"viewOne"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
else if (ctrl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    NSLog(@"Two");
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"showView"] isEqualToString:@"viewOne"]) {
        self.viewOne.hidden = NO;
        self.viewTwo.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (...) {

    }
}
```

The above should work when you toggle the segment control. In each `if` you can toggle the visibility of two views. You would create the different views as a subview of the main view; one on top of the other. You would need to hide one view either in Interface Builder or in the viewDidLoad (I would suggest storing the current view in NSUserDefaults and showing that view when the user first loads the view controller).